# converting 3D slice to 2D image with vtk

Tags: python, vtk, scientific-computing

Is there a way using vtk to get a 2D image from the 3D coordinates and associated data of a cut plane (that can be oblique) ?

Here is a snippet of my code that reads the structured grid and sets a cutplane:

```
self._reader = vtk.vtkXMLStructuredGridReader()
self._reader.SetFileName(filename)
self._reader.Update()

self._reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().SetActiveScalars("Intensity")

plane = vtk.vtkPlane()
plane.SetOrigin(self._reader.GetOutput().GetCenter())
plane.SetNormal(0, 0, 1)

planeCut = vtk.vtkCutter()
planeCut.SetInput(self._reader.GetOutput())
planeCut.SetCutFunction(plane)

# THIS GIVES THE 3D COORDINATES OF THE POINTS OF THE CUT PLANE
print planeCut.GetOutput().GetPoints()
# THIS GIVES THE DATA ASSOCIATED WITH EACH OF THE POINTS
planeCut.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetAttribute(0)

cutMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cutMapper.SetInputConnection(planeCut.GetOutputPort())
cutMapper.SetLookupTable(table)
cutMapper.SetScalarRange(0,100)

cutActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cutActor.SetMapper(cutMapper)

self._renderer.AddActor(cutActor)

self._iren.Render()
```

thank you very much for your help

Eric

Answer (score 2):

vtkCutter produces a vtkPolyData output. What you want is vtkImageReslice.

Create a vtkImageReslice object, a vtkTransform to use as its parameter, set the image as its input and you're done. If you want to change the slice, modify the transform appropriately and Update or Render.

Something like this:

```py
reslice = vtkImageReslice()
transform = vtkTransform()
transform.Translate(x,y,z)
transform.Rotate(thetaX, thetaY, thetaZ)
reslice.SetResliceTransform(transform)
reslice.SetInputConnection(blah)
nextAlgorithmOrMapper.SetInputConnection(reslice.GetOutputPort())
```

Note: SetInput is deprecated in VTK 6.0+. For new code, use either first.SetInputConnection(other.GetOutputPort()) or first.SetInputData(data) (if you're already on 6, otherwise, the second form is still first.SetInput(data) which you'll have to port later). SetInputConnection creates an algorithm connection - ie, if you call Update() on the consumer, the producer will also be updated automatically, and so on down the chain. If you use the second form, in 5.x it also creates an algorithm connection, but in 6, it doesn't. You'll have to manually call Update on each of your algorithms.

Basically, use SetInputConnection when you're hooking together two vtkAlgorithms or mappers.